# Div's visibility based on model property in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The following code not working. please help me to figure out this

```
 <div style="visibility: @(@Model.HasBackUp ? "block" : "none")"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the `@` in front of the Model so your code should look like this:

```
<div style="display: @(Model.HasBackUp ? "block" : "none")"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="display: @(Model.HasBackUp ? "block" : "none")"/>
```

Comment: No. Its not working i tried both display and visibility properties. :(